# Where do I find the redirect URL that UIPath needs when using UIPath connector in MuleSoft?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

I am using the UIPath connector which is a certified connector so Mulesoft does not provide support for it or have documentation for. UIPath said I need to ask MuleSoft support the the redirect URL and MuleSoft says they don't know what it is and they don't support it.

Has anyone used the connector that can provide some guidance?

Comment: You mean to use the UIPath connector from UIPath in a Mule application. MuleSoft (the company) Support obviously doesn't know anything about it. If you ask for help here provide an example of what exactly are you trying to do and the configuration you are trying to set.

Comment: When setting up OAuth2.0 in MuleSoft, you typically define a callback or redirect URI as part of the application configuration. This is the URL that external services (like UiPath) will redirect to after the user has authenticated. In MuleSoft, this URL is usually tied to an HTTP listener in your API that can handle the OAuth callback.

as @aled said please let us know what are you trying to do